# How can I setup a callback to be executed when function returns in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like this in a class method. Basically, I have a code snippet that needs to be executed, regardless of the function returns successfully or throws an exception.

```
class A {
 private:
  int b;
 public:
  void foo() {
    bool bar = false;

    // I want this to be executed when foo returns/throws.
    auto callback = [&]() {
       b = bar ? 1 : 2;
    }

    // logic that may have return/throws.
  }
};
```

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to use RAII.

Check out these slides http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C -- particularly ScopeGuard11, for a good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `ScopedGuard` referenced in [rlbond's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656021/how-can-i-setup-a-callback-to-be-executed-when-function-returns-in-c#comment49374793_30656021) you can have a `function_guard` which stores the callback and invokes it in its destructor:

```c++
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct function_guard {
    template<class U, class... Args>
    function_guard(U u, Args&&... args) : callback_(std::bind(u, args...)) { }
    ~function_guard() {
        callback_();
    }
private:
    std::function<T> callback_;
};
```

Comment: What does '0x499602D2' stand for?

Comment: @StraightLine [Nothing special. :)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/155b56ed918feddf)

Answer (score 1):

Use it similar to what std::lock_guard does it. 
Make an object that takes in a callback in its constructor, and then execute the callback in its destructor.
e.g

```
class CallbackCaller{

(function pointer) ptr;

public:
CallbackCaller((function pointer) _ptr)
{
  ptr = _ptr;
}

~CallbackCaller()
{
   (*ptr)();
}
};
```

This way, when the function returns, and the object is destroyed, it will call your function pointer. You can improve this class and make it reusable by using templates! 
Enjoy.